# Re-installing Grub2, getting error on grub-probe

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, re-installation, grub2

When i was trying to reinstall grub for my ubuntu 10.04 from a 11.04 live cd, i was getting error as:

```
grub-probe error: error: cannot find a drive for /media/Linux/boot/grub (is /dev mounted?)
```

My ubuntu partition is sda6 and i was using the following command:

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/media/Linux/boot /dev/sda6 --recheck
```

Please resolve this error for me..

Answer (score 2):

I rebooted and the issue wasn't any more.

Answer (score 1):

6nagi9, the shortest way is, from a terminal in a live CD environment:

1. `sudo fdisk -l` (to figure out in which patition is your boot directory located)
2. `sudo mount /dev/sdxX /mnt`
3. `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda --recheck` (to install in the MBR of your first harddrive)

It should say: `Instalation finished.  No error reported.`

...umount your `/mnt` and reboot.  If you have a recent windows install probably you won't see it in your grub menu, bet that's no sweat, from within your ubuntu install run `sudo update-grub` and it will find your windows install and update your grub.cfg accordingly.

Hope it helps...

Comment: --root-directory doesn't work anymore with new grub(1.99), process you are giving is meant for older grub.